# parsing JSON object to get filelocation

Tags: json, parsing

i am new to JSON. Here i am facing problem how to get file location from JSON object,  i am using javascript to parse the json

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "binaries": [
        {
            "fileLocation": "http://images.clipartpanda.com/sports-equipment-clipart-black-and-white-soccer-ball-hi.png",
            "username": "testuser3",
            "description": "The company required the 28-year-old's help on a matter the directors felt could affect the share price: its Wikipedia page. Short, uninteresting .",
            "createdAt": "2015-02-01T21:47:07.000+0000",
            "updatedAt": "2015-02-01T22:42:16.000+0000"
        },
        {
            "fileLocation": "http://images.clipartpanda.com/sports-equipment-clipart-black-and-white-soccer-ball-hi.png",
            "username": "Sumanth",
            "description": "Sample",
            "createdAt": "2015-02-23T21:37:13.000+0000",
            "updatedAt": "2015-02-23T21:43:11.000+0000"
        },
        {
            "fileLocation": "http://images.clipartpanda.com/sports-equipment-clipart-black-and-white-soccer-ball-hi.png",
            "username": "as",
            "description": "as",
            "createdAt": "2015-02-02T22:46:00.000+0000",
            "updatedAt": "2015-02-27T22:06:18.000+0000"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

i want to read all file locations from JSON object .
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What language are you trying to parse it in? What does your code do so far?

Comment: @james  thanks for replay . i want to parse in javascript

Comment: @james i made a ajax call to my database and get the response as above. in this using javascript i want to get fileLocation

Comment: @james i stored assigned json object to variable data.  and i did data.

Comment: data._embedded.binaries[1].fileLocation.  but it is showing _embedded not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to access fileLocation looks right:

```
data._embedded.binaries[1].fileLocation
```

Before that, to parse your data use:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/01aL5upc/
Note that I did remove whitespace and the apostrophe in 28-year-old's in the fiddle, to put it in to a string rather than an ajax request.